# Struct containing a (nested) mapping cannot be constructed

Tags: solidity

```
function addProductToStore(
    string memory _name,
    string memory _category,
    string memory _imageLink,
    string memory _descLink,
    uint256 _auctionStartTime,
    uint256 _auctionEndTime,
    uint256 _startPrice,
    uint256 _productCondition
) public {
    //开始时间需要小于结束时间
    require(
        _auctionStartTime < _auctionEndTime
        // "开始时间不能晚于结束时间"
    );
    //商品ID自增
    productIndex += 1;
    //product对象稍后直接销毁即可
    Product memory product = Product(
        productIndex,
        _name,
        _category,
        _imageLink,
        _descLink,
        _auctionStartTime,
        _auctionEndTime,
        _startPrice,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,
        ProductStatus.Open,
        ProductCondition(_productCondition)
    );
    stores[msg.sender][productIndex] = product;
    productIdInStore[productIndex] = msg.sender;
}
```

Comment: Hi wanshunzhong! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! There's not enough code to try it, can you include a more complete example? What's the exact error message?

Comment: 代码链接：https://cxybb.com/article/weixin_34387284/91785195

Comment: Sorry, but I can't follow that article. Do you have a link to a github repo with the whole code?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If a struct has nested mapping you should use storage modifier

```
Product storage product = Product( ...
```

it means you can't get temporary variable of which struct that contains mapping

Comment: 代码链接：cxybb.com/article/weixin_34387284/91785195